# Synonyms for "exchange partner"

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

I'm currently writing a letter to my Canadian student exchange partner whose name I don't know. So, instead of writing "exchange partner" all the time, are there any useful synonyms? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: More context would help - what exactly Is a student exchange partner? What words have you considered and rejected? What research have you done? Possibly [pen pal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pen-pal) _someone with whom you exchange letters as a hobby, esp. someone in another country_

Comment: I would think you would exchange names with 1st communications ... problemo solved?